# "Index Match" VBA not returning an output without errors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to implement an index-match function through VBA and although everything seems like correct to me, I cannot figure out why it's not working.

You can view my test file at http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?68989-VBA-Code-for-IndexMatch-Function-not-working-without-error

The code I used is:

```
Sub IndexMatch()


Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, dataWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim IndexRng As Range, MatchRng As Range


Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")
Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Population")


destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dataLastRow = dataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set IndexRng = dataWs.Range("A2:A" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchRng = dataWs.Range("C2:C" & dataLastRow)




For x = 2 To destinationLastRow


On Error Resume Next


destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
    IndextRng, _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0))


Next x


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: IndextRng should be IndexRng   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Comment: I  corrected the typo and added "Option Explicit" but still no results.

Comment: Try removing this `On Error Resume Next` you are just skipping errors, this will highlight the error and give you some details

Comment: Yes it actually highlight the following error: Run Time Error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class. I also tried to to remove from the code the "WorksheetFunction" as suggested in https://software-solutions-online.com/unable-to-get-match-property-of-worksheetfunction/ but the result after that is #N/A.

Comment: I realized what was incorrect: Set IndexRng = dataWs.Range("B2:B" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchRng = dataWs.Range("A2:A" & dataLastRow)

'IndexRng.Select
For x = 2 To destinationLastRow

'On Error Resume Next

destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
    IndexRng, _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0))...thanks for pointing me towards the right ditrection.

Comment: Glad to help.  Cheers